# drawRect not responding to setNeedsDisplay (mcve)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am aware that this question has been asked many times, but I have found a partial resolution.

I have a custom class GraphView in which I have several sliders which change the graph parameters and instigate a redraw using [self setNeedsDisplay]. The only way I can get the setNeedsDisplay to work is to have the view of type GraphView just under the View Controller and the slider just under (and inside) the GraphView (in the storyboard hierarchy). This is problematic since the slider must be inside the graph.

Here is an mcve @interface:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface GraphView : UIView
@property float red;
@property   __weak IBOutlet UITextField *redout;
@property   UIBezierPath *aPath;
@property   CGPoint aPoint;
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect;
- (id)  initWithFrame:(CGRect)frameRect;
- (IBAction)red_rabi:(id)sender;
```

Here is the mcve @implementation:

```
#import "GraphView.h"

@implementation GraphView

- (id)  initWithFrame:(CGRect)frameRect
{
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frameRect]) != nil)
    {
        _red=1.0;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];
    int i;
    NSString *redstr;
    float width, height;
    width = rect.size.width;
    height = rect.size.height;
    _aPath =[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:rect] ;
    [_aPath setLineWidth:1.0];
    _aPoint.x=0.0;
    _aPoint.y=0.0;
    [_aPath moveToPoint:_aPoint];
    redstr = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"%6.2f", _red];
    for (i=1;i<400;i++)
{
        _aPoint.x=i*width/400.0;
        _aPoint.y=height-height*(sin(i*_red/30.)+1.0)/2.0;
        [_aPath addLineToPoint:_aPoint];
}
        [_aPath stroke];
}


- (IBAction)red_rabi:(id)sender
{
    NSString *redstr;
    UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)sender;
    _red= slider.value;
    redstr = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"%6.2f", _red];
    _redout.text = redstr;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

@end
```

If you place a generic View just underneath the View Controller (which I didn't touch), change the generic View's class to GraphView, and place a slider and TextField inside the GraphView (connecting them to the outlet and action), this app will generate a few cycles of a sine wave with the frequency controlled by the slider and its value displayed in the TextField.

If you want the slider and TextField in another view, one must use an enveloping view for all three items (GraphView, slider, text) and one cannot connect the slider and TextField to the GraphView using Ctrl_drag to the GraphView.h file. To remedy this, I placed a generic Object at the highest level and renamed it GraphView - I could then connect the slider and TextField. Although the Textfield reads correctly, the slider doesn't update the GraphView.

By the way, essentially the same code with the GraphView and slider in separate views works perfectly in OS X.

Sorry for the length of this query and thanks!

Comment: Please give some example code to demonstrate the problem to us, and that we could use to reproduce your problem. It isn't clear from your description. I suspect you are calling `-setNeedsDisplay` on a different view from the one that implements `-drawRect:`, but it's impossible to tell for sure.

Comment: I'd suggest you create the simplest possible reproducible example of the problem (a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), because `setNeedsDisplay` should do it fine. I wonder if something else might be going on.

Comment: What is this "mcve" you keep saying?

Comment: It is a "minimal, complete and verifiable example" as suggested by Rob.

Comment: @warrennn - I tried your code and it worked fine. I'd suggest you check two things: First, double check the frame of the `GraphView` itself (you can either use the view debugger or pause execution and enter `po [[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription]` at `(lldb)` prompt). Incorrect constraints could place it somewhere unexpect. Second, I would double check that your `red_rabi` method is getting called at all. In short, confirm that your outlet hooked up correctly. I took your code and updating the slider updates the `GraphView` just fine, so it's got to be something simple.

Comment: Rob, the funny thing is that the slider was correctly connected to the action, since the textview was being correctly updated as the slider moved. As I stated below, the problem was still somehow in the connection, since directly dragging from the circle was the correct way to do it (I was unaware of this approach -- I thought Ctrl-dragging was necessary). Live and learn!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! Due to an interesting SO post from three years ago (about connecting to subviews of UIView), I discovered that one merely drags (not Ctrl_drag!) from the action or outlet circle (in the .h file) to the control and that's it. Works perfectly even when the controls are in a different view from the subclassed UIView. Works equally well with outlets as with actions though you always drag away from the circle.

Thanks to all for their help.